# R package builds on Windows, but fails to run example - crashes R session

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I am building a [package](https://github.com/sn248/sundialr) which successfully compiles on both Windows and Linux, macOS. The package uses `Rcpp` to provide an interface to a C library for solution of ODE (Ordinary Differential Equations).

The package passes all checks on `macOS` and `Ubuntu` (tested via `travis-ci`). The package successfully builds on `Windows 10` machine also, but running a simple example (which runs successully on other platforms, crashes the `R` session).

I am at my wits-end, trying to find out what is going wrong. Message from `Appveyor` is as pasted below.

This example can be found at https://github.com/sn248/sundialr/blob/master/inst/examples/cv_Roberts_dns.r

and runs successfully on other platforms.

Any pointers on how to debug this here would be very helpful, thanks!

```
* running examples for arch 'i386' ... ERROR
Running examples in 'sundialr-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:
> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: cvode
> ### Title: cvode
> ### Aliases: cvode
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '#include <Rcpp.h>
+ 
+ using namespace Rcpp;
+ 
+ typedef NumericVector (*funcPtr) (double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot);
+ 
+ // [[Rcpp::export]]
+ NumericVector cv_Roberts_dns (double t, NumericVector y, NumericVector ydot){
+   ydot[0] = -0.04 * y[0] + 1e04 * y[1] * y[2];
+   ydot[2] = 3e07 * y[1] * y[1];
+   ydot[1] = -ydot[0] - ydot[2];
+ 
+   return ydot;
+ 
+ }
+ 
+ // [[Rcpp::export]]
+ XPtr<funcPtr> putFunPtrInXPtr() {
+ 
+   XPtr<funcPtr> testptr(new funcPtr(&cv_Roberts_dns), false);
+   return testptr;
+ 
+ }')
> 
> 
> # R code to generate time vector, IC and solve the equations
> time_t <- c(0.0, 0.4, 4, 40, 4E2, 4E3, 4E4, 4E5, 4E6, 4E7, 4E8, 4E9, 4E10)
> my_fun <- putFunPtrInXPtr()
> df <- cvode(time_t, c(1,0,0), my_fun , 1e-04, c(1e-8,1e-14,1e-6))
```

Comment: Does it work on the Windows machines used by  winbuilder or r-hub?

Comment: @RalfStubner - No, the example fails there as well. I think there is something wrong with the package. Even though it builds, it does not execute any example properly on `Windows`. Why it happens only on `Windows` is beyond my understanding currently.

Comment: I do not have an explanation. Windows is "different", and I see no other way than debugging the package. That is extremely difficult vi CI, so I suggest to get an actual Windows machine for this. For example, the Windows variant of the DSVM on MS Azure might work. And you get some free credits when you sign up. I haven't tried that, though ...

Comment: @RalfStubner - Thank you for your suggestion. For some reason a few macros defined in `C` code did not work on Windows. I have fixed that now. I have stumbled upon another issue - the examples from the package run on `64` bit version of R, but not on `32` bit (on win-builder). Do you have any insights on why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: What are the memory requirements of the example? Have you tried running with `valgrind`and `gctorture`?

Comment: I haven't tried with `valgrind`, I am having issues with installing it on my `macOS` machine. I tried running the example with `gctorture(on = T)` on a `Windows` machine with `32-bit` `R`. It does not show me any message until the very last command (`cvode`). When `cvode` function is run, however, the R Studio session crashes with `RStudio R Session has stopped working` message. Really frustrating!

Comment: When R crashes one often gets better error messages running R from the console.

Comment: Just an update - Although I could not find the solution to this problem, including files from the updated version of the underlying C library (i.e., 3.1.1. instead of 3.1.0) does not give me this problem anymore.